# How to add Customized ListView inside navigation drawer? Different views in each row

Tags: android, listview, drawer

Hi I'm new to Android development and I have to create a navigation drawer with different items on it.

The first row should contain a

> Button

. The next three rows should contain

> TexViews

, and the last row should contain an

> EditText

I'm gone as far as creating the layout but I haven't the idea of how to call that inside the adapter.

Comment: Why do you want to use a ListView for this?

Comment: because I'm NEW to android and I don't know any other way YET.

Answer (score 1):

The Navigation Drawer isn't limited to a ListView. Maybe this is the reason why you want to choose one. You can use any View / ViewGroup to build your Drawer. Try a LinearLayout with some child Views of your choice. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <Button
        .../>
    <TextView
        .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

It's just an example, to show that you don't have to stick to a ListView as your Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

In `getView`, you need to check what type the item from `getItem(position)` is and inflate the proper layout based on that.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    NavDrawerItem item = getItem(position);
    if (item.getType() == BUTTON_ITEM_TYPE)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_button, parent, false);
        //get references to individual views, etc.
    }
}
```

with an item interface like

```
public interface NavDrawerItem
{
    public static final int BUTTON_ITEM_TYPE = 1;
    public static final int TEXTVIEW_ITEM_TYPE = 2;

    public int getId();

    public String getLabel();

    public int getType();
}
```